# FTP software for linux, handling space, special character, utf-8

Tags: utf-8, ftp, special-characters, filenames

I have a hard time with FTP. I'm need to handle a large amount of file, which names contains spaces and UTF-8 character :

> My filename été@xksm'winter.ext

I've tried ftp command, and yafc but neither works. When the filename contain accent, it simply didn't work. When it contains special character, I can escape them, but it's a pain in the a**.

Do you have a solution please ?

N.B: I can't use ssh, otherwise it will be more easier with rsync...

Comment: This is usually dependant on the server and client both supporting  RFC 2640 which bring UTF-8 support to FTP. Ensure your server and client support it. On Linux, ensure your locale is "*.UTF-8" and your filenames are UTF-8 encoded

Comment: When asking a question, please explain what "didn't work".

Comment: Voting to migrate to ServerFault

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack You can't really do something else than downloading or uploading file while using ftp... If it didn't work, it didn't dl or up. I don't have access to the server, but it's support UTF-8 because I have no problem using FileZilla. Thx for your help

Comment: Oh, so no file listing, file moving, feature listing or extended commands? You might want to tell the writers of RFC 959. Did you read RFC 2640 and checked your server for the UTF-8 FEATure?

Answer (score 1):

After trying all ftp client available : lftp, yafc, ftp, and NcFTP >>

NcFTP is only one handling completion without issue, and all special character.

So if you encountered any problem of this kind, use NcFTP.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is not a standard feature of FTP, so you need to check that your server supports UTF-8 and use a client that supports UTF-8 as defined in RFC 2640.

Some non-UTF-8 FTP servers support 8bit codepages so you may strike lucky that your server and client use the same codepage.

Check your server for UTF-8 support by using a client that has a command line or allows you to send arbitrary commands (WinScp and Cyberduck do). Type/Send:

```
FEAT
```

Which lists the server's features. You should see somewhere in the response:

```
UTF8
```

This means that your server supports UTF-8 filenames. Now, make sure that your client supports UTF-8 features.